# Installing Drush on Mac

Tags: drush

I am installing Drush on my Mac following the instructions I found on https://linode.com/docs/websites/cms/drush-drupal/.

Everything works perfect, but I got stuck at the end while creating the symbolic link. Please find the error below.

```
Mudasirs-iMac:/ mudasir$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush

ln: /usr/bin/drush: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You should look into homebrew it is a package manager for Mac. Basically, a tool for installing tools.

Comment: Another tool that you can use to install drush is composer. Which is a php package manager.

Comment: You simply don't have the permissions to `usr/bin` anymore as in earlier versions of mac. Use `usr/local/bin` instead. So the command should be adjusted to `sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to `/usr/bin` on OSX (since Yosemite).

Add your symlink to `/usr/local/bin` instead, and make sure that's in your path.

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get to know that its in my path or how can I add this to my path

Comment: Depends, but for bash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025980/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-in-path-on-mac

Comment: @Mudasir, after creating the symlink into /usr/local/bin, just try typing "dru" and hit "Tab" key to see if it completes it to "drush". Then that means that /usr/local/bin is in your path. Also you can check by typing "echo $PATH" into terminal and find /usr/local/bin there. If it's not in your path environment, then simply follow the link Clive put above and add it to your path. Make sure you do "source ~/.bash_profile" or logout/login to your mac after changing .bash_profile to get the new path variable loaded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you guys help, when I am looking for path it shows me /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin, I can find /usr/local/bin there, but while creating the symblink, I still have the same issue.

Comment: `usr/local/bin` is already in the path by default.

Comment: True but some enterprising individual could have removed it @leymannx, was just covering all bases I guess :) Thanks for adding the command sample, I removed `sudo` as it's not required and may cause issues for some people